# Chrome App Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive

Tags: google-chrome

in local chrome app i run script

```
document.getElementById("qdiv").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="qq.html" ></object>';
```

appear error:
*Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-CTnJLHYITJvEmEmQ7A4vB7gicU0e0h2NTRTijgMHFN0='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.*

I try to add permission to manifest
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' ; object-src 'unsafe-eval'; default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'"

but absolutely not help